# How may DataFrame.cache() prevent OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded?

Tags: pyspark

TL;DR: Why when `dataframe.select("data.*")` causes `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`, the  `dataframe.cache().select("data.*")` may work just fine?

I have a large DataFrame which is used as input to a Python UDF. The code look likes this:

```py
def convert(row: Row) -> Row:
    return row
convert_udf = udf(convert, schema)
output_df = input_df.select(
    convert_udf(
            struct("col1", "col2", "col3", ...)
        ).alias("data")
    )
```

I need the final DataFrame to look exactly the same as the input: each column in the top level.

```py
# 1. Nested data works fine but not in the correct final format.
output_df.write...
# 2. Cached and then unested. Works fine.
output_df.cache().select("data.*").write...
# 3. Unested data takes long time and ends with
#    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
output_df.select("data.*").write...
```

Why is `.cache()` preventing the memory issue? Is this the best way of preventing this error?

Comment: Because when you `.cache()` It materializes the dataframe at the point and forgets the lineage of the dataframe. It is always recommended to materailize the dataframe from time to time and not let the lineage grow both for memory and performance issues. I found this the hard way.